# better understanding of callback functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, anonymous-function

I am reading this function in a book, and I don't understand how the anonymous function
is passed the thirst three arguments?

This is what I understand

```
function multiplyByTwo(a, b, c, callback) {
  var i, ar = [];
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ar[i] = callback(arguments[i] * 2);
  }
  return ar;
}
```

but not this

```
myarr = multiplyByTwo(1, 2, 3, function(a){return a + 1});
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: in javascript functions are almost like objects, you can define it like this 'var func = function(a,b,c){return a + b + c + 1};' and call it like this 'func(1,2,3)' or this 'func.apply(this, [1,2,3])'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments detailing the contract of the `multiplyByTwo` function would be helpful here:

```
// multiplyByTwo
// num num num (num -> x) -> x[]
function multiplyByTwo(a, b, c, callback) {
  ...
```

This means that the function takes four arguments, and returns an array of `x`.  `x` can be any type.  The first three arguments are numbers.  The fourth argument to the function is actually a function itself.  This function takes a number, and returns an `x`.  Again, `x` can be any type, but it is the same type throughout the contract.

Inside the `multiplyByTwo` function, the callback function is called once for each of the other arguments.  The result of each of these calls is added to an array, which is the return value of `multiplyByTwo`.

The `arguments` variable is a special variable in javascript, which, inside the scope of a function, gives access to all of the arguments to that function, as an array.

The callback function is bound to the name `callback` in the scope of the `multiplyByTwo` function.  It can then be called as any other function, such as by appending parentheses and arguments.  The anonymous function that you gave when you called `multiplyByTwo` can then be referenced by that name.

So, in the example given, `multiplyByTwo` is called with four arguments: `1`, `2`, `3`, and an anonymous function.  Inside the scope of the `multiplyByTwo` function, these arguments are bound to the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `callback`, respectively.  These arguments can also be referenced through the special `arguments` array.  In the example, both methods are used to reference the arguments.  The first three are referenced using the `arguments` array inside a loop, and the fourth argument is referenced using its name, as in `callback(...)`.

Comment: I understand how callback is used in the loop, but how does it work for the anonymous one. Do you call that one arguments[4](arguments[i])

Comment: You could call the function with `arguments[4](arguments[i])`, but you can also call it by the name `callback`, since you bound it to that name by naming the arguments (well, you named the first four arguments anyway).

Comment: The first one was an example with a function attached to a variable.The second part should execute the same way according to the book, but it diddn't gave an example how the anonymous function was being called?

Comment: note on the side: arguments is an array, which are zero based so it should be arguments[3](arguments[i])

Comment: @Richard, I added some more clarification.  Does that help explain how the anonymous function is called?

Comment: @pkaeding, I understand it now. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous function is called 3 times in the loop, each time passing in a different argument.  The first time it passes in `arguments[0]`, which is `a` (and `arguments[1]` would be `b`, etc.).  `arguments` is a property of the currently executing function and refers to the parameters passed into the function.  In JavaScript, you don't have to name your parameters, or access them by their names, or even pass in all of the named parameters.

Comment: how do I replace callback for the anonymous one inside the loop?

Comment: `callback` is a reference to the anonymous function.  Since the 4th parameter is named `callback`, it refers to the 4th parameter passed in, which is a function.  As such, your once anonymous function is now named `callback` within the scope of `multiplyByTwo`.